# GitHub open source files to different IDEs

Tags: c++, github, ide, codeblocks, projects-and-solutions

I am relatively new to C/C++  - most of my coding experience has been writing single use mathematical programs with very specific applications in Matlab, Fortran and the occasional C with low project complexity (1-5 files), and typically coded by me alone. In an attempt to become familiar with more complex C/C++ coding syntax and larger projects, I’ve download a GitHub open source project:

https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit

This toolbox comes with an VS13 project file so I can easily load it into VS13; however, I have been using CodeBlocks. Two questions:

1: How can I open a VS13 project in another IDE such as CodeBlocks?  I could load in every library and then add each of the search directories to the linker, and essentially replicate the environment, but there has to be an easier way since for very large projects, this could take a long time.

2: Many of the GitHub toolboxs don’t have project files for any IDE. How can someone create an IDE project file? For example this tool box (https://github.com/shogun-toolbox/shogun).

Comment: Your example `https://github.com/shogun-toolbox/shogun` uses CMake to generate project files for IDEs. You create a CMakeLists.txt file and use CMake to generate project files for any of the supported compilers / ides.

Comment: http://www.cmake.org/

Comment: @drescherjm, Thanks, I saw that. However, none of the cmakelist files work properly. They either don't map all the directories correctly in CodeBlocks or I get error in the middle of using cmake: cmtrycompileExec1372736121. Is there a more general process that does not rely on a 3rd party application? Many of the tool boxes don't have cmake files.

Comment: @drescherjm, just tried to use cmake to also create a VS13 project file, and that also failed due to "error: could not find svn for checkout of MSIntTypes" which seems like a common error for this took box, http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.ai.machine-learning.shogun/5281

Comment: It's easy to install svn. Search for Tortoise svn. And no that is certianly not a common error for CMake. I have been on the cmake mailing list for 6+ years. Most things do not require svn these days.

Comment: Also something that requires swig and python on windows is not going to be an install that a beginner should attempt with or without CMake.

Comment: ***Is there a more general process that does not rely on a 3rd party application?*** CodeBlocks does not support Visual Studio. And Visual Studio does not support CodeBlocks. If you want to switch between the two you either have to use a third party tool or manually create project files yourself.

Comment: Perhaps the "common error" was misleading, it was in reference to the shogun toolbox, not cmake.

Answer (score 0):

- make sure you have latest code-blocks version installed
- just go:

> file -> import project -> MS VS project -> C or C++

That works perfect for me!

Comment: was this the answer to your question?